# React redux render data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a problem with React and Redux and I imagine finding a solution here ... On my application, I have a function when loading the page componentDidMount which calls a function that lists images on my page. I also have a button that calls the same function.

My problem: when I click on the button, although I already have the list of displayed images, I have the same list twice and if I click again, the same new images are added. It's only when I reload the page that everything comes back to the way it started, I searched in vain, Redux keeps the data and adds the same data each time we call it unless we reload the page.

```
case FETCH_GALLERY_SUCCESS:
return {
...state,
loading: false,
// stories: state.stories.concat(action.payload),
stories: [...state.stories, ...action.payload],
currentPage: action.currentPage,
totalPages: action.totalPages,
totalStories: action.totalStories,
error: ""
}
```

Finilly I found this :

```
case FETCH_GALLERY_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                stories: [...state.stories, ...action.payload].filter( 
                    (storie, index) => index === [...state.stories, ...action.payload].findIndex( 
                        elem => elem.id === storie.id && elem.id === storie.id
                        )
                    ),
                currentPage: action.currentPage,
                totalPages: action.totalPages,
                totalStories: action.totalStories,
                error: ""
            }
```

Comment: Is it the `stories` object that contains the images? If so, it seems like every time you dispatch `FETCH_GLLERY_SUCCESS` you'll be adding the same stories over and over again. You might need to check for conflicts before adding the stories. Or perhaps you can get away with just setting stories equal to action.payload? `stories: action.payload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick has it nailed in the comment already, but to explain some more:

```
stories: [...state.stories, ...action.payload],
```

This is coming down to the way the `...` spread operator works. It's taking the original, pre-action `state.stories`, spreading that in an array, then following that up by spreading the newly arrived `action.payload`. Basically, you've extended what was originally there with the newly arrived info. If your new info is just a repeat of your old info, you'll see a duplicate batch on the second action, then a triplicate batch on the third and so on. Each subsequent `FETCH_GALLERY_SUCCESS` basically adds another copy of what was already there (assuming the newly fetched gallery `stories` are just the same as the old).

Some ways to solve this:

- If you only ever care about what came in the most recent fetch, just change it to `stories: action.payload`. What you had before is dropped, but that's probably fine depending on your use-case. (Looks like you'll also need to update your `totalStories` and other such values as well.)
- Maybe the later fetch will provide new, additional images beyond what's already there? If that's the case, you could do some kind of [array `.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) operation on the newly fetched batch to filter out duplicates, then add on the non-duplicates to the front or end of your Redux `stories` key in a similar fashion to what you have now.
- Maybe something else if you have a different use-case? You could have a pre-processing step before you do the `return` of the new state that can have access to the old `stories` state (via `state.stories`) and to the newly fetched payload of stories (via `action.payload`). Write some code to create whatever new combination `stories` state should be the result, then return that at the end. Don't forget to also handle your other state keys like `totalStories` in your custom code too.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now, but in the second situation "Maybe the later fetch will provide new, additional images beyond what's already there? If that's the case, you could do some kind of array .filter operation on the newly fetched batch to filter out duplicates, then add on the non-duplicates to the front or end of your Redux stories key in a similar fashion to what you have now." how to filter my table after each addition of elements in my reducer ?

Comment: @ChrisIssifou The specifics of how you set up the new `stories` will depend on your design, what you're trying to accomplish, etc. I assume each story has some kind of ID or unique value in it -- you'll probably want to use that in some way to pick what stays and what gets dropped during the process. Take a look at the array `.filter` method I mentioned above. You could also try search SO for things like "remove duplicates from array", things like that.